# Autopay paypal on the site, how to save in the database information about the payment?

Tags: php, paypal

I need to make an auto payment on the site, the user will enter his data once and then there will be an auto payment using this data. How can I implement this. What api paypal should I use for this? I using php, mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This payment method seems like PayPal Recurring payment.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/?mark=recurring%20payment

Comment: I thought there is some kind of interface for sending requests with the card number, cvv, and the expiration date.